# org/kivy/android/PythonActivity java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: python, java, pyjnius

I am trying to implement Java in Python using Pyjnius.

My code:

```
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
context = cast('android.content.Context', currentActivity.getApplicationContext())
```

While running, I am getting the following exception:

```
>           PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')

sarasds/ds_init/DataStoreInit.py:59: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jnius/reflect.py:229: in autoclass
    c = find_javaclass(clsname)
jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi:26: in jnius.find_javaclass
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>   ???
E   jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: org/kivy/android/PythonActivity java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

jnius/jnius_jvm_dlopen.pxi:91: JavaException
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

in Buidoze.spc file, add requirements = pyjnius

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).